# How to use Service --status-all | grep running in java code to get resullt my code not giving result?

Tags: java, linux, terminal

hi i am trying to get result of linux running service i am trying to use this code,

```
    public void runningservices()
{

    try {
        String line;
        char c = '|';
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("service --status-all "+c+" grep running");
        BufferedReader input =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
        {
String[] split = line.trim().split(" ");
            System.out.println(line);  
        }
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

i tried this code but output is empty no error how to get running this code ?? this command is running on linux terminal and giving result

hopes for your suggestiong thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

As to my info , the service --status-all must run under root privileges 
try to use

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("service --status-all "+c+" grep running");
```

****Note that the user must be from sudoers***  *

hope this would help

Comment: as i am using this code but not getting result and what about the "user must be sudoers" i have not undertood this thing ?? i am using RHEL 5

Comment: Sudoers are the users who can run root commands with no need to login as root just type "sudo command -comand-params" http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo